# How to extract icloud data through JavaScript / PHP by providing "icloud credential"?

Tags: ios, sdk, icloud, icloud-api, icloud-drive

We are looking for any type of SDK / API or references available for extracting the icloud data Like (Messages, Photos and videos, Browser history, Call history, Contacts, Installed apps, Contacts (live), Photos and videos (live), Location (live), WhatsApp messages, Skype messages, Calendar, Line messages, Kik messages, Viber messages, Facebook messages, WeChat messages, Snapchat messages, File list, Browser history (live) ) by providing the icloud credential as an input.

We are trying to make a web services / Software similar to https://www.reincubate.com/contact/support/icloud-api/#working who use to provide the licence API for extracting data from icloud server for icloud users.

Have went through icloudKit JS and also icloud storage API ( Key-value storage & iCloud document storage) However not clear as they might help in the thing we want to achieve.

Apple might be providing the API / SDK for extracting icloud data as their are many icloud backup extractor software software available and need to know by what backend they are working.

Examples of icloud backup extractor software softwares are mention below:

1. http://www.iphonebackupextractor.com/
2. http://www.iskysoft.com/data-recovery/icloud-backup-extractor.html

Comment: Hi, did you get the answer for this.?

Answer (score 0):

> #### [InflatableDonkey](https://github.com/horrorho/InflatableDonkey)

I suspect those libraries are using the undocumented iCloud backup API, which is based off CloudKit.

There is a Java library for accessing this API and downloading the snapshot backups here:

- https://github.com/horrorho/InflatableDonkey

Comment: Thanks for reply @inflatabledonckey can you share your email id, wish to disciss on same in detail